# URL for the "Bridge to Kubernetes" in Visual Studio

Tags: kubernetes

I am attempting to containerize some console apps that we have. I'm trying to follow this tutorial to get everything running locally:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/bridge-to-kubernetes-vs

I have the sample to-do app running, so that's great. Now I'm trying to get a home grown C# console app deployed. I was successful in getting the console app deployed to my local docker, but am stuck in the "Bridge to Kubernetes".

It's asking for an Application Url, but this isn't a service which is exposed, it's just a console app that connects to external resources -- nothing connect to the app.

Does it matter what I put in here? It's a required field.

Comment: Actually it's a service...did you check the content of https://github.com/Azure/Bridge-To-Kubernetes/blob/main/samples/todo-app/deployment.yaml

Comment: I did. Can I not use "Bridge to Kubernetes" without a URL?

Comment: If you did then you know that there is a url for the service. Anyway, when you use Bridge to Kubernetes, it should pick automatically the url from the dropdown, like is this image https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/media/bridge-to-kubernetes-vs/configure-bridge-debugging.png

Comment: I understand there is a url for the service in the demo, however in my application, it is not an external service, it's a stand-alone console app. Nothing talks to it. So I don't know what to put in there since it's a required field.